# Fullcalendar | Jquery hover function doesn't work anymore after view changing

Tags: javascript, jquery, symfony, fullcalendar

## The Context

Hi everybody,

I'm using [Fullcalendar](https://fullcalendar.io/) to display availabilities and bookings of properties (houses) in a CRM application developed under Symfony 3.

The calendar is functional. We have `.fc-event-container` element to display the bookings and .fc-bgevent for the availabilities as below.

[fullcalendar.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W6x8z.png)

What I've added after, is the possibility to know, by hovering a cell (.fc-bgevent), who has set the availabilities and when. These informations are retrieved from the database, stored into a custom attribute « data-informations » during the render of each cell (.fc-bgevent) and finally displayed above the calendar view container as below.

[fullcalendar-hover.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a3Tqg.png)

To show you how I have achieved that, I put the code of the using files below.

### Controller

```
   //src/LD/PlatformBundle/Controller/Properties/indexController.php
  public
  function viewAction(Request $request, $id) {

      $events = $manager - > getRepository('LDPlatformBundle:Availabilities') - > findBy(array('idProperties' => $id));

      $Availa = array();

      foreach($events as $event) {
          ...
          $Ava['user'] = $event - > getIdUsers();
          $Ava['updateDate'] = $event - > getDateModifAvailabilities();

          if ($Ava['updateDate'] != null) {
              $Ava['updateDate'] = $Ava['updateDate'] - > format('D d-M-y');
          } else {
              $Ava['updateDate'] = "unknonw date";
          }
          if ($Ava['user'] == null) {
              $Ava['user'] = 'unknown user';
          }
          $Ava['informations'] = "Created by ".$Ava['user'].
          " on ".$Ava['updateDate'];
          $Availa[] = $Ava;
      }

      return $this - > render('LDPlatformBundle:Properties:view.html.twig', array(
          'Availa' => $Availa,
      ));
  }
```

### View

```
//src/LD/PlatformBundle/Resources/views/Properties/view.html.twig
<script >

    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
            schedulerLicenseKey: 'GPL-My-Project-Is-Open-Source',
            header: {
                left: 'prev,next today',
                center: 'title',
                right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay,listMonth'
            },
            navLinks: true, // can click day/week names to navigate views
            businessHours: true, // display business hours
            editable: false,
            eventOverlap: false,
            events: [{ % include('FrontBootstrap/ajaxPlanning.html.twig') %
            }],
            eventRender: function(event, element) {
                $(element).attr('data-informations', event.informations);
            },
            nextDayThreshold: "01:00:00"
        });
        $('.fc-view-container').prepend('<div id="informations-date"><span></span></div>');
        $('#informations-date').css('visibility', 'hidden');
        $('.fc-bgevent').hover(function() {
            var informations = $(this).attr('data-informations');
            $('#informations-date span').text(informations);
            $('#informations-date').css('visibility', 'visible');
        }, function() {
            $('#informations-date').css('visibility', 'hidden');
        });
    }); 
</script> 
<style >

    #informations - date {
        height: 20 px;
    }

    /* Disable hover */
    .fc - content - skeleton,
    .fc - bgevent - skeleton {
        pointer - events: none
    }

    /* Enable hover on .fc-bgevent, .fc-bgevent-skeleton child and .fc-event-container */
    .fc - bgevent,
    .fc - event - container {
        pointer - events: auto;
    }
</style>
```

### Events

```
    //app/Resources/views/FrontBootstrap/ajaxPlanning.html.twig
{ %
    for ava in Availa %
} {
    start: ('{{ ava.start|date("Y") }}-{{ ava.start|date("m") }}-{{ ava.start|date("d") }}'),
    color: '{{ ava.color }}',
    rendering: 'background',
    informations: '{{ava.informations}}',
} { %
    if loop.last %
} { %
    else %
}, { % endif %
} { % endfor %
}
```

## The Problem

Now, the thing is, when I change the view by selecting other month (june, july...) or other range (week, month...), the functionality doesn't work anymore. I know the problem comes from Jquery because I still have the attribute « data-informations » on the cells of others views. I first thought that the hover function doesn't work cause its targets elements that are on the DOM when the function is called. That's why I also try to declare the function and call it into [viewRender](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/viewRender) parameter but it didn't solved the problem.

```
  //src/LD/PlatformBundle/Resources/views/Properties/view.html.twig
 $(document).ready(function() {
     // console.log(items);
     console.log(Availa);
     $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
         schedulerLicenseKey: 'GPL-My-Project-Is-Open-Source',
         header: {
             left: 'prev,next today',
             center: 'title',
             right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay,listMonth'
         },
         navLinks: true, // can click day/week names to navigate views
         businessHours: true, // display business hours
         editable: false,
         eventOverlap: false,
         events: [{ % include('FrontBootstrap/ajaxPlanning.html.twig') %
         }],
         eventRender: function(event, element) {
             $(element).attr('data-informations', event.informations);
         },
         viewRender: function(view, element) {
             console.log('ok');
             $('.fc-bgevent').hover(function() {
                 console.log('ok');
             });
             getDateInformations();
         },
         nextDayThreshold: "01:00:00"
     });
     $('.fc-view-container').prepend('<div id="informations-date"><span></span></div>');
     getDateInformations();

 });

 function getDateInformations() {
     $('#informations-date').css('visibility', 'hidden');
     $('.fc-bgevent').hover(function() {
         console.log('ok');
         var informations = $(this).attr('data-informations');
         console.log(informations);
         $('#informations-date span').text(informations);
         $('#informations-date').css('visibility', 'visible');
     }, function() {
         $('#informations-date').css('visibility', 'hidden');
     });
 }
```

I think there is surely a special feature of the hover function that I don't know.

Comment: I think you'd have to do it in `eventAfterAllRender` instead of `viewRender` because, as the documentation (of viewRender) says, viewRender runs after the plain view has been drawn, but the events are not necessarily loaded into it at that time - that is done asynchronously, so there's a good chance your events are still not in the DOM at that time.

Comment: Alternatively, outside the calendar config entirely (but within your document.ready) you could use jQuery delegated event handling to tackle it e.g. `$('#calendar').on("hover", ".fc-bgevent", function(){
                    console.log('ok');
                });`

Comment: I also note that inside getDateInformations() you declare the same event handler again - so in the viewRender you're duplicating that, which isn't good. Make sure it's only called once for each element. BTW there is no such word as "informations", the plural of "information" is "information" - the same.

Comment: Thank you so much @ADyson ! eventAfterAllRender works like a charm. This is my first topic on stack. How do I mark it as resolved ? Also thank you for the grammar correction :)

Comment: I will add it as a full answer, and then you can mark it resolved (by clicking the tick next to the answer so it goes green). I didn't add it as the answer to begin with as I wasn't 100% certain it would work, but now you've confirmed it is correct I can do that confidently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd have to add the event handler in fullCalendar's `eventAfterAllRender` instead of `viewRender` because, as the documentation (https://fullcalendar.io/docs/viewRender) says, `viewRender` runs after the plain view has been drawn, but the events are not necessarily loaded into it at that time - that is done asynchronously, so there's a good chance your events are still not in the DOM at that time.

```
eventAfterAllRender: function(view)
{
  $('.fc-bgevent').hover(function() {
    console.log('ok');
  });
}
```

See also https://fullcalendar.io/docs/v3/eventAfterAllRender